# How to make a Count Down Timer in Java

Tags: java, timer, countdown

I was developing this application to Shutdown/Restart and Hibernate the Computer in a user-given time. I have attached a picture of the application I was developing.User can select Hours, Minutes or Seconds to shutdown/restart or hibernate the computer within the time user is given. I have attached the code sample I was using but It didn't count down the time

```
public void cal() {
    int seconds = (int) jSpinner1.getValue();
    int minutes = (int) jSpinner2.getValue();
    int hours = (int) jSpinner3.getValue();

    int SECONDS_IN_A_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60;

    Calendar day = Calendar.getInstance();

    day.set(Calendar.SECOND, seconds);
    day.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
    day.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);


    long difference = day.get(seconds + minutes + hours);
    long allSeconds = difference / 1000;

    long days = allSeconds / SECONDS_IN_A_DAY;
    long secondsDay = allSeconds % SECONDS_IN_A_DAY;

    final long secondsinaDay = secondsDay % 60;
    final long minutesinaDay = (secondsDay / 60) % 60;
    final long hoursinaDay = secondsDay / 3600;

    final java.util.Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.printf("%d hours, %d minutes and %d seconds\n", hoursinaDay, minutesinaDay, secondsinaDay);
            jLabel5.setText(String.valueOf(hoursinaDay));
            jLabel6.setText(String.valueOf(minutesinaDay));
            jLabel7.setText(String.valueOf(secondsinaDay));

            //What should be in here if I needed to count down the Timer??????
        }
    }, 1000, 1000);

}
```

[image: The picture of my Application]

Comment: Which is the issue?  What does "it didn't count time" mean?

Comment: Have you tried to use a Thread or a Job for your counter?

Comment: `hoursinaDay`, for example, is always the same value...

Comment: Your TimerTask does not reduce the remaining time value. It should decrease the remaining seconds by one each time.

Comment: @david Java (an in general most of computers systems) are not real-time, so there is no guarantee that the task will execute **exactly** each 1 seconds; with enough repetitions the accumulated error may be significant. It is way better to, for each execution, get the current time and calculate how much it remains than to simply "delete 1 second" each time, even if sometimes it causes to "skip" a second.

Comment: The line `long difference = day.get(seconds + minutes + hours);` makes no sense. The get method requires a field code. Why are you adding seconds to minutes to hours? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get(int)  Arn't you getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Comment: @ChristianFries: I was wrong there, I should've made hours and minutes to seconds and add them and make the difference

Comment: @Code Bae: But still the get method won't give you the difference. You need to construct two dates: The date of termination and the current date. The current date has to be constructed inside the run(). Then calculate the difference inside the run().

Comment: Termination time is control by the User. He is the one that controlling the time duration to count
 down. How can I do this ?? can you help me?
@ChristianFries

Comment: I'm getting the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. can you describe why? @ChristianFries

Answer (score 1):

It is hard without you explaining properly what happens, but at the very least you should be calculating the values of the time left **inside** the task.

The code outside the task is executed just once, it is the code inside the `run()` method of the task that will be executed each second.

Otherwise, even if the task executes, it will always put the same values in the labels.

Comment: I cannot think of making the time counting down @SJuan76